# backup database on dropbox using API

Tags: php, database, api, backup, dropbox

I have used DROPBOX API to upload backup on my dropbox+php...And I'm on the half way

1)I have made local-connection and took backup file in my local

2)Then I have added key,secret(in config.json) and generated access-token(dropbox_sqlbackup.php) in proper place
**Now Where I am stuck is:**

I am not able to upload the generated backup file of database on my dropbox...

my error message is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The Dropbox SDK uses 64-bit integers, but it looks like we're running on a version of PHP that doesn't support 64-bit integers (PHP_INT_MAX=2147483647). Library: "C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\dropbox-sdk\lib\Dropbox\RequestUtil.php"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\dropbox-sdk\lib\Dropbox\RequestUtil.php:22
```

now i have tried other answers on stackoverflow to remove "64 bit integer conversion" but not getting what to do??

the demo i have follwed is :

http://www.inboundhorizons.com/use-php-and-dropbox-api-to-automatically-backup-mysql-databases-to-dropbox/

Which is just to get reference...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution....
Don't try the demo in your local system,it will not work in local,You only need to upload the code in live and test it..!!

NOTE:In local your backup file will be generated in your folder but it could not be uploaded on dropbox account